# List out all Site Pages having custom/3rd party Web Parts in SharePoint 2007 team site

Tags: web-part, 2007, team-sites, third-party-software, id

I am trying to get a list of all the site pages (with link) in a Web App or a site collection which contains custom/third-party web parts. Don't want to list out any Out-of-Box parts.

I tried `?contents=1` trick but it only lists for a single page and not for the whole site collection. Suppose, there are more than 300 Site collections. We can't go to every single page manually.

Also, I found a DB query found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498409/sharepoint-find-where-webpart-is-in-use)

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.SiteID, D.WebId, W.FullURL as WebURL, D.Id As DocumentId,
                D.DirName, D.LeafName, tp_ID As WebPartSK
FROM       dbo.Docs D WITH (nolock) 
INNER JOIN dbo.Webs W WITH (nolock) ON D.WebID = W.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.WebParts WP WITH (nolock) ON D.Id = WP.tp_PageUrlID
WHERE WP.tp_ListId Is Null AND WP.tp_Type Is Null AND WP.tp_Flags Is Null
      AND WP.tp_BaseViewID Is Null AND WP.tp_DisplayName Is Null 
      AND WP.tp_Version Is Null
AND WP.tp_WebPartTypeId='<your web parts id>'
```

This can find where the web parts are used in a whole content DB. But it needs a Web Part Type ID. In my case, I could not find the WebPartTypeId same.

> I tried with Collabion/Bamboo web parts. Wherever these webparts are
>   used, they have different IDs.

Please help me in Listing out all Site Pages having custom/3rd party Web Parts in **SharePoint 2007 Team Sites**